# javascript/reactjs how do I display a file in local system in my UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a web application built on react.js which would have a table with some 10 rows and in each row there would be an option to view a file. The view option would download a file from the server and save it locally. The UI should display the downloaded file and open it within the application. This feature should work on Chrome,Safari,Firefox and Internet explorer.

I saw some links which suggested file:/// but it only works on some browsers.Is there any unified mechanism for all browsers?

Comment: You can download the file directly into the application, without saving it.  Is there a reason you want to save it, or is that just because you think you need to?

Comment: The file is stored as a base64 encoded data on server.Is it possible to display the pdf/jpeg in a separate url without downloading it to local system?

Comment: You can't show anything in your browser that isn't downloaded, but you don't do that yourself.  You simply point the browser or application at the resource Url and the browser takes over from there.  If you want to display an image (for example) that's stored on the server in Base64 format then you're really better off serving it as an image.  The alternative is to set an image tag's src attribute to the Base64 encoded image, and it will display it.  Sorry, but the question is a quite vague so it's difficult to answer you with certainty.